# HermiT entailments that contain negation

Tags: java, owl-api, reasoning, reasoner, hermit

Is there a way to get inferences from **HermiT** reasoner that contain negation (`ObjectComplementOf`)? Here is what I tried:

```java
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
IRI iri = IRI.create("http://www.test.owl");
OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(iri);

OWLClass clsA = dataFactory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(iri + "#A"));
OWLClass clsB = dataFactory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(iri + "#B"));
OWLAxiom axiom = dataFactory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(clsA, clsB.getComplementNNF());

OWLIndividual john = dataFactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(iri + "#JOHN"));
OWLClassAssertionAxiom assertionAxiom = dataFactory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clsA, john);

ontology.add(axiom);
ontology.add(assertionAxiom);

OWLReasonerFactory reasoner_factory = new ReasonerFactory();
OWLReasoner reasoner = reasoner_factory.createReasoner(ontology);

OWLOntology inferred_ontology = manager.createOntology();

// Create an inferred axiom generator, and add the generators of choice.
List<InferredAxiomGenerator<? extends OWLAxiom>> gens = new ArrayList<>();
gens.add(new InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator());
gens.add(new InferredClassAssertionAxiomGenerator());
gens.add(new InferredDisjointClassesAxiomGenerator());
gens.add(new InferredEquivalentClassAxiomGenerator());

// Create the inferred ontology generator, and fill the empty ontology.
InferredOntologyGenerator iog = new InferredOntologyGenerator(reasoner, gens);
iog.fillOntology(dataFactory, inferred_ontology);
```

The (cleaned) result:

```java
//KB:   A SubClassOf not(B), A(JOHN)
ENTAILMENTS:{
    SubClassOf(A owl:Thing),
    SubClassOf(B owl:Thing),
    DisjointClasses(A owl:Nothing),
    DisjointClasses(B owl:Nothing),
    DisjointClasses(A B),
    ClassAssertion(owl:Thing JOHN),
    ClassAssertion(A JOHN)
}
```

**My question:** How can I also get this assertion:
`ClassAssertion(ObjectComplementOf(B) JOHN)`?

Comment: @Ignazio is spot on! The only thing to add perhaps is if you want to understand why the entailments are in fact infinite, you may want to look at [this paper](https://ceur-ws.org/Vol-745/paper_22.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the reference @HenrietteHarmse! I will certainly take a look!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to generate all inferred axioms that use class or property expressions. The reason for that is that the list of class (and property) expressions is infinite, so the reasoner would embark on an impossible task if it tried to generate all axioms of that kind.

If you have a criterion for selecting a finite subset of class expressions (e.g., the list of complements for each named class in the ontology) you could implement an axiom generator that asks the reasoner whether those classes have instances, and create the axioms that way.

Reasoners could also do the same, to provide a partial answer to a question with infinite answers - but, far as I'm aware, there are no reasoners which do that. HermiT certainly does not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 2 questions. First one, I browsed a bit in the owl-api and hermit code and I see that the `Reasoner` class has for example a method `getSuperClasses()` that is forming a `Set<HierarchyNode<AtomicConcept>>` to later return. Since this is hard coded instead of (I guess) a `LiteralConcept`, isn't it then impossible to get negated superclasses? Second one, since the expressions are infinite, the reasoner limits its output only by focusing on Atomic Classes?

Comment: I'm not suggesting getSuperClasses() - as you point out, its return type is limited to named classes (worth noting that the limit is on named classes not atomic classes). I'm suggesting getInstances() which takes as input a class expression and would return all individuals of that type. Note: the direct parameter should be set to false, to get all individuals and not just direct instances.